# JSX Formatting with React Link or a tag hrefs?

Tags: html, css, react-router, jsx

I'm trying to map an array where each element becomes a separate link, separate by a greater than symbol `>`

So an array of `[hello, world, foo, bar]` becomes

[hello](https://www.google.com/) > [world](https://www.google.com/) > [foo](https://www.google.com/) > [bar](https://www.google.com/)

How can I properly do this in JSX? I'm trying something like

```
const path = ["Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar"]

return (
    <div className='breadcrumbs'>
    {props.user ? 
        path.map((entry) => <span><Link>{entry}</Link>&gt;</span>) : <></> }
    </div>
);
```

With this CSS:

```
.breadcrumbs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Yet I get this outcome:

[image]

How can I keep everything in line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because your `Link` component renders a `block level element`. Hence forcing the `>` to go to next line.

You can give your inner span a classname and then assign it property of `display:flex`. That will make sure it stays in a row.

Also make sure to give your elements a proper unique `key` when rendering through `map`.

```
const path = ["Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar"]

return (
    <div className='breadcrumbs'>
    {props.user ? 
        path.map((entry,index) => <span key={`breadcrumb-item-${index}`} className="breadcrumb-item"><Link>{entry}</Link>&gt;</span>) : <></> }
    </div>
);
```

```
.breadcrumb-item{
 display:flex;
 gap:2px;
 align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: I used a flex for the outside container but not the inside, but I did in fact try this solution shortly after posting my question, before receiving and answers, and it worked.